# Why do i get out of bounds when using FileStream.Write?

Tags: c#

When I execute this code.

```
Random R = new Random();
        byte[] BA = new byte[8192];
        R.NextBytes(BA);
        FileStream FS = new FileStream(@"D:\Test.txt", FileMode.Append);
        long end = FS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        if (FS.CanWrite == true)
        {
            FS.Write(BA, (int)end, BA.Length);
            FS.Flush();
        }
        FS.Close();
```

It will work the first time I run it. If I try to run it a second time I get this error.

> Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater
>   than the number of elements from index to the end of the source
>   collection.

I do not undertand this error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

You're passing your arguments wrong. In:

```
FS.Write(BA, (int)end, BA.Length);
```

the second argument specifies the offset *in the byte array* to copy from, not the offset in the file you're writing TO. Effectively you're copying 8192 bytes in the first pass, and in the second pass, you're telling FileStream to copy from BA starting at the 8193rd byte, which of course crashes, because it's out of bounds. See the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.write.aspx).

You can fix it simply by passing 0 to FS.Write, telling it to start at the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's just saying that you're trying to access data at addresses that go beyond the "bounds" of the array.

To put it in simple terms, imagine you had an array of 10 elements.  What would you expect if you asked "Start at the 5th element and give me the next 10 elements?"  It's going to throw an error and tell you the offset (the 5th element in this case) and the length (10 in this case) are out of bounds.